# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver even after adding jar file

Tags: java, mysql

I have added the connector jar file as mentioned in other posts, but even after that, the error didn't go away. there are many questions being asked and answered for the same problem, most of them talk about adding the jar file which I already did, still didn't get it through. I am using intellij IDE

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: jitenderchand
  Date: 08/12/21
  Time: 11:36 AM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<%
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "password@123";
    String sql = "select * from users.student where  id =1";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    rs.next();
%>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Root Cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:657)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:152)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
      </properties>

  <dependencies>
                <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>      </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
      </plugin>                </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: please add your pom.xml to the question

Comment: @saw303: I have added the pom.xml

Comment: I think you have added the mysql jar file manually since it´s not part of your pom.xml. imo the easiest way to make it work is to add the dependency to your pom.xml (i.e. this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.27) and clean install again

Comment: Go to https://start.spring.io/ and generate a new project. Add mysql Driver as dependency. Download the project and open the genarated pom.xml file. Take a close look at what deps are there. Copy the mysql related to your pom.xml. Rebuild and re-run your project.